# Show Old Data OF User When Edit Profile

Tags: wordpress

In my website there're user roles **STUDENT** and **TEACHER**. Now I edit user profile and change user role TEACHER to STUDENT. I want to send mail but I also want to display old value. I am using the following code:

```
function user_profile_update($userid) {
    $userdata = get_userdata($userid);//get updated user data 
    print_r($userdata);// print values
    die("check");//stop the screen
}
add_action('profile_update','user_profile_update');
```

Please help me for print old values.

Comment: What do you think where the old data goes, once you have changed it?

Comment: I want to send mail like this : Your old Role is Student And New Role Use Teacher

Comment: You could add a hook to edit_user_profile_update and send a mail from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to display old user role

Comment: I see you didn´t get my rhetorical question the first time, so I will make it clear: *Once you change the user role the old role is lost. It´s wiped from the database.* So you would have to add user defined fields to save it or whatever. Please put some effort in collecting more information on this.

Comment: Thanks i find out solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found answer myself if this help any one please use so i post answer 
set_transient function are save data for save old data and use it when send mail.

function sr_old_user_data_transient(){

  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );

  foreach( $user_meta as $key=>$val ){
    $user_data->data->$key = current($val);
  }

  // 1 hour should be sufficient
  set_transient( 'sr_old_user_data_' . $user_id, $user_data->data, 60 * 60 );

}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'sr_old_user_data_transient');

// Cleanup when done
function sr_old_user_data_cleanup( $user_id, $old_user_data ){
  delete_transient( 'sr_old_user_data_' . $user_id );
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'sr_old_user_data_cleanup', 1000, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, here is an alternative based on the original question and code:

They had the right idea using `profile_update()` but forgot to add the additional parameters, `userID` then `$show_old_values`....

```
function user_profile_update($userid, $olduserdata) {
    $userdata = get_userdata($userid);//get updated user data 
    print_r($userdata);// print values
    print_r($olduserdata);// print old values
    die("check");//stop the screen
}

add_action('profile_update','user_profile_update', get_current_user_id(), 2);
```

Where you need to insert the `userID` to get to the number of parameters parameter which we update to 2, the two parameters are `$userid` and `$old_user_data`...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update